# Prevent account merge in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I've been trying to figure out how to prevent the auto-merging of Meteor accounts when logging in with mail & services.

*Example:*

User logs in with mail for account 1 - he then connects with twitter account.
Afterwards he logs out and logs in with mail for account 2 - he then connects with the same twitter account.
Now account 1 and 2 get merged into one and the mail from account 2 gets pushed into the registered_emails array in mongo.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to the account merge issue described above.
I installed the `mondora:connect-with` package and used `Meteor.connectWith('twitter')` instead of `Meteor.loginWithTwitter()`.

This package adds an error callback and prevents account merging - Example:

```
Meteor.connectWith('twitter', function (error) { 
  // Show user an error message
});
```